Why is the curvature a horizontal form?
Let $\pi:P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle, let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$ and let $\omega\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ be a connection form, i.e.
$$R_g^*\omega=\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\omega\ \ \  \text{ for each $g\in G$,}$$ $$   \omega(a(v))=v \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ for each $v\in\mathfrak{g}$}.$$
Here $a:\mathfrak{g}\to \Gamma(TP)$ is the infinitesimal action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $P$:
$$a(v)_p:=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \ p\cdot \exp(tv),\ \ \ \text{ for each $p\in P$}.$$
Let $K$ be the associated curvature, i.e.
$$K=d\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega].$$
Why $K$ is a horizontal form?

The exterior covariant derivative is always a horizontal form (because by definition, $D\alpha$ equals $d\alpha$ composed with horizontal projections). Your “definition” of the curvature (which I’d really rather think of as a theorem, namely Cartan’s structure eauations) is equivalent to $K=D\omega$, and so the result trivially follows. The answer provided below, with the case distinction of horizontal vs vertical is essentially how one proves Cartan’s structure equation.

$K$ is horizontal if it vanishes when evaluated on a vertical section. Let $p \in P$ a generic point:  let's distinguish two cases:

If $X_p, Y_p$ are both vertical vectors of $T_p P$, then we can find $V,W \in \mathfrak g$ such that the induced right-invariant vector fields  $\tilde V, \tilde W$ satisfy $X_p = \tilde V_p$ and $Y_p = \tilde W_p$. Then
\begin{align*}
d\omega_p(X_p,Y_p) &= \mathcal L_X (\omega(\tilde W))_p - \mathcal L_Y (\omega(\tilde X))_p - \omega_p([X,Y])\\
&= \mathcal L_{\tilde V}(\omega (\tilde W))_p - \mathcal L_{\tilde W}(\omega (\tilde V))_p - \omega(\widetilde{[V,W]})_p\\
&= [V,W] - [W,V] -[V,W]\\
&= -[V,W],
\end{align*}
because by the second property of $\omega$ in your question, $\omega(\tilde V) = V$. On the other hand
\begin{equation*}
[\omega, \omega](X,Y)_p = 2[\omega(X), \omega(Y)]_p = 2[\omega(\tilde V), \omega(\tilde W)]_p = 2[V,W].
\end{equation*}
This proves $K(X,Y) = 0$ on vertical sections.
If $X_p \in V_p$ is a vertical vector and $Y_p \in H_p$ is horizontal, then we can find $V \in \mathfrak g$ such that $X_p = \tilde V_p$ as before, and $Y \in \Gamma(H)$ a horizontal vector extending $Y_p$. Notice that $[\tilde V,Y]$ is horizontal, indeed
$$
[\tilde V,Y]_p = \frac d {dt} \Big|_{t = 0} dR_{\operatorname{exp}(-t V)} Y_{p. \operatorname{exp}(t V)} \in H_p
$$
As $Y_{p. \operatorname{exp}(t V)} \in H_{p. \operatorname{exp}(t V)}$ and $dR_{\operatorname{exp}(-t V)}$ preserves horizontal vector fields.
Then
$$
d\omega_p(X_p,Y_p) = \mathcal L_{X_p} (\omega(Y))_p - \mathcal L_{Y_p}(\omega(\tilde V))_p - \omega([\tilde V, Y])_p = -\mathcal L_{Y}(\omega(\tilde V))_p = - \mathcal L_Y V = 0,
$$
where both $\mathcal L_{X_p} (\omega(Y)$ and $\omega([\tilde V, Y])$ equal zero because $H_p = \ker \omega_p$ kills all horizontal vector fields. On the other hand $\mathcal L_Y V = 0$ as $V$ is constant. Finally
$$
\frac 1 2 [\omega, \omega](\tilde V, Y)_p = [\omega(\tilde V), \omega(Y)]_p = 0
$$
again as $Y$ is horizontal. Thus
$$
K(X_p,Y_p) = 0.
$$


Thank you very much!
